# Spring MVC: DeferredResult with encoded URLs: Invalid encoded sequence

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, tomcat8, spring-async

I'm using **Spring MVC 4.1.6** with **DefferedResult**. It's work fine. But if I did request with using encoded url then I received error.

> **Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> execute() {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    execute(deferredResult);
    return result;
}
```

> **Request**

```
GET http://localhost:8080/app/50%25%20off
```

> **Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid encoded sequence "% off"
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.decode(UriUtils.java:355) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeInternal(UrlPathHelper.java:418) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeRequestString(UrlPathHelper.java:409) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeAndCleanUriString(UrlPathHelper.java:391) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getRequestUri(UrlPathHelper.java:279) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(UrlPathHelper.java:213) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinServletMapping(UrlPathHelper.java:175) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(UrlPathHelper.java:154) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:292) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:56) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:299) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1120) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) ~[spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:639) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$1.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:222) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.doInternalDispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:384) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:390) [catalina.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1711) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:649) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.28]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

This problem with decode URL after some result was set in **DefferedResult**, but **HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()** is already decoded from UTF-8. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem with Apache Tomcat and it was fixed since 8.0.34.

**[Apache Tomcat 8.0.34 changelog:](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.0.34_(markt))**

[59317](http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59317): Ensure that HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI() returns an encoded URI rather than a decoded URI after a dispatch. (markt)

Answer (score 1):

> **Resolution 1: urlDecode flag is set to false**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUrlDecode(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

}
```

> **Resolution 2: ignore decoding after some result was set in DefferedResult**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private static final String AFTER_CONCURRENT_HANDLING_STARTED = "afterConcurrentHandlingStarted";

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUrlPathHelper(new UrlPathHelper() {

            @Override
            public String decodeRequestString(HttpServletRequest request, String source) {
                return request.getAttribute(AFTER_CONCURRENT_HANDLING_STARTED) == null
                    ? super.decodeRequestString(request, source) : source;
            }

        });
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptorAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                request.setAttribute(AFTER_CONCURRENT_HANDLING_STARTED, AFTER_CONCURRENT_HANDLING_STARTED);
            }

        }).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

}
```